# Error in returning the value from the function

Tags: c#, asp.net, function

I have created one function to return int value for device type as follows ;

```
public int getDeviceType(string device)
    {
        int temp;
        if (device.ToLower() == "android")
        {
            temp = 1;
        }
        else if (device.ToLower() == "ios")
        {
            temp = 2;
        }
        return temp;

    }
```

And i wanted to return the type for device.

But it gives me an error that

```
 "Use of unassigned variable temp"
```

How can i solve it ?

Thanks.

Comment: just as a note, "temp" will never be set to: 2. Are your sure this is the way you should be doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just initialize temp with default value like below

```
public int getDeviceType(string device)
{
    int temp = 0;
    if (device.ToLower() == "android")
    {
        temp = 1;
    }
    else if (device.ToLower() == "ios")
    {
        temp = 2;
    }
    return temp;

}
```

Comment: just do it and compile and then see. I know int has default value 0 here by default value i mean you want to return if both if and if else evaluates to false then what value should be returned

Answer (score 1):

Initialize `temp` to `0` because if it do not go in any of the cases then what value of temp will it return.

I know `int` default value is `0` but still in these cases you have to initialize it. Till then it won't run.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause analysis of this behavior when integer variable has default value 0 and why it's required to initialize it.

For local variables, the compiler has a good idea of the flow - it can see a "read" of the variable and a "write" of the variable, and prove (in most cases) that the first write will happen before the first read.

This isn't the case with instance variables. Consider a simple property - how do you know if someone will set it before they get it? That makes it basically infeasible to enforce sensible rules - so either you'd have to ensure that all fields were set in the constructor, or allow them to have default values. The C# team chose the latter strategy.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the compiler want's to ensure you initialize all your variables. Both local and instance. So in theory, you always must initialize all of your variables.

However, because the compiler can't determine if an instance variable is initialized before it first gets read, the compiler implicitly initializes all instance variables to their default values.

So the exception is not that a local variable doesn't get initialized automatically, the exception is that an instance variable *does* get initialized automatically.